# How can i send/receive data over bluetooth between ANDROID app and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

My goal is : send ***via bluetooth*** certain string comand **from my Android app** to a **Raspberry Pi device** so it can runs a script,and after it is done, send back the message to my Android app

My approach:

1.[I used this tutorial for inspiration of my bluetooth server class that runs on my Android app (and convert it to kotlin)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5M4o5dGigbY&list=PLFh8wpMiEi8_I3ujcYY3-OaaYyLudI_qi&index=17)

2. Used this python code(from my Pi3) for tryn to connect as a client on my server class

```
import socket

serverMACAddress = 'F8:8F:07:3D:7A:7B'
port = 2
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH, socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.BTPROTO_RFCOMM)
s.connect((serverMACAddress,port))
while 1:
    text = input()
    if text == "quit":
        break
    s.send(bytes(text, 'UTF-8'))
s.close()
```

**The problem**: Rpi3 connects just at the level of my phone os bluetooth, but the server client that i wrote in my android app doesnt accept it, also, can't send/receive data from one to another (ofc)

I tried a lot of things in this app for a lot of time,changed a lot of libraries for the client app in python, nothing worked, i spent at least 5 weeks on this part.

I will provide you my kotlin code(note: i dont use ClientClass but maybe it will help posting it, ofc that i want that android client class that i dont use, somehow be translated to python to work on my pi) and also pics with what i have achieved:

```
class TrackYourWorkoutFragment : Fragment() {

private lateinit var binding: FragmentTrackYourWorkoutDataBinding

var MAC_ADDRESS = "E4:5F:01:0A:7D:20"
var MAC_ADDRESS_SAMSUNG = "F8:8F:07:3D:7A:7B"
val DEVICE_NAME = "raspberrypi"
var bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket? = null
var isConnected: Boolean = false
private lateinit var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter
private lateinit var sendReceive: SendReceive

companion object {
    private const val APP_NAME: String = "RealStats"
    var SHARED_UUID: UUID = UUID.fromString("f4b18e71-c048-43a0-99cc-06f99eb6b654")
    private const val STATE_LISTENING = 1
    private const val STATE_CONNECTING = 2
    private const val STATE_CONNECTED = 3
    private const val STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED = 4
    private const val STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED = 5
}

private val viewModel: TrackYourWorkoutFragmentViewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory {
        TrackYourWorkoutFragmentViewModel(
            onConnectToPiClick = { startServerSoPiConnects() },
            onStartWorkoutClick = { startWorkout() }
        )
    })[TrackYourWorkoutFragmentViewModel::class.java]
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_track_your_workout,
        container,
        false
    )
    binding.viewModel = viewModel
    binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    (requireActivity() as? AppCompatActivity)?.supportActionBar?.setTitle(R.string.toolbar_track_your_workout)
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    enableBluetooth()
}

var handler = Handler { msg ->
    when (msg.what) {
        STATE_LISTENING -> binding.tvInfoConnection.text = "Listening"
        STATE_CONNECTING -> binding.tvInfoConnection.text = "Connecting"
        STATE_CONNECTED -> binding.tvInfoConnection.text = "Connected"
        STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED -> binding.tvInfoConnection.text = "Connection Failed"
        STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED -> {
            val readBuff = msg.obj as ByteArray
            val tempMsg = String(readBuff, 0, msg.arg1)
            binding.tvInfo.text = tempMsg
        }
    }
    true
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private fun startServerSoPiConnects() {
    //val piDevice: BluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MAC_ADDRESS)
    val serverClass = ServerClass()
    serverClass.start()
}

private fun startWorkout() {
    val startMessageForPi = "s"
    sendReceive.write(startMessageForPi.toByteArray())
}

private fun enableBluetooth() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        requestMultiplePermissions.launch(
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            )
        )
    }
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private val requestMultiplePermissions =
    registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()) {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled) {
            bluetoothAdapter.enable()
            Toast.makeText(this.context, "Bluetooth enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

private inner class ServerClass @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") constructor() : Thread() {
    private lateinit var serverSocket: BluetoothServerSocket

    init {
        try {
            serverSocket = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(
                APP_NAME,
                SHARED_UUID
            )
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun run() {
        var socket: BluetoothSocket? = null

        while (socket == null) {
            try {
                val message: Message = Message.obtain()
                message.what = STATE_CONNECTING
                handler.sendMessage(message)
                socket = serverSocket.accept()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
                val message: Message = Message.obtain()
                message.what = STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED
                handler.sendMessage(message)
            }

            if (socket != null) {
                val message: Message = Message.obtain()
                message.what = STATE_CONNECTED
                handler.sendMessage(message)
                sendReceive = SendReceive(socket)
                sendReceive.start()
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

private inner class ClientClass @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") constructor(deviceR: BluetoothDevice) :
    Thread() {
    private var device: BluetoothDevice
    private lateinit var socket: BluetoothSocket

    init {
        device = deviceR
        try {
            socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SHARED_UUID)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun run() {
        try {
            socket.connect()
            val message = Message.obtain()
            message.what = STATE_CONNECTED
            handler.sendMessage(message)

            sendReceive = SendReceive(socket)
            sendReceive.start()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            val message = Message.obtain()
            message.what = STATE_CONNECTION_FAILED
            handler.sendMessage(message)
        }
    }
}

private inner class SendReceive(socket: BluetoothSocket) :
    Thread() {
    private var bluetoothSocket: BluetoothSocket
    private lateinit var inputStream: InputStream
    private lateinit var outputStream: OutputStream

    init {
        bluetoothSocket = socket
        var tempIn: InputStream? = null
        var tempOut: OutputStream? = null

        try {
            tempIn = bluetoothSocket.inputStream
            tempOut = bluetoothSocket.outputStream
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        if (tempIn != null) {
            inputStream = tempIn
        }
        if (tempOut != null) {
            outputStream = tempOut
        }
    }

    override fun run() {
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var bytes: Int

        while (true) {
            try {
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer)
                handler.obtainMessage(STATE_MESSAGE_RECEIVED, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget()
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

        }
    }

    fun write(bytes: ByteArray) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(bytes)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

}

[initial state of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAXvP.jpg)

[after starting the server, by clicking connect to pi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feMTO.jpg)

[after clicked connect to pi(started the server) and runned the pi program   note: the text doesnt change, it remains in connecting state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbh8A.jpg)

***If someone manages to solve this somehow, or provide me some usefull notes at least, please, i want to send you a NICE(i hope) gift.***

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY FOUND IT, THIS IS THE ANSWER
import bluetooth
import threading
import time
import random
import sys

```
#address="00:17:E8:B2:50:28"
#uuid="66841278-c3d1-11df-ab31-001de000a901" 
#service_matches = bluetooth.find_service( uuid = uuid, address = address )

uuid="f4b18e71-c048-43a0-99cc-06f99eb6b654"
while True:
  try:
    print ("Searching ...")
    try: service_matches
    except NameError:
      service_matches = bluetooth.find_service( uuid = uuid)
    else:
      if not service_matches:
        print ("without address")
        service_matches = bluetooth.find_service( uuid = uuid)
      else:
        print ("with address")
        service_matches_with_addr = bluetooth.find_service( uuid = uuid, address = "F8:8F:07:3D:7A:7B" )
        if service_matches_with_addr:
          service_matches = service_matches_with_addr
        else:
          continue

    if service_matches:
      first_match = service_matches[0]
      port = first_match["port"]
      name = first_match["name"]
      host = first_match["host"]
      print ("connecting to \"%s\" on %s" % (name, host))
      sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
      sock.connect((host, port))

      print ("Happy Spamming")

      while True:
        try:
          string = 'test' + random.choice('abcdefghij') + '\n'
          try:
            sock.send(string)
            time.sleep(0.5)
          except:
            print ("Android no longer interested in my spam, socket not valid, going back to searching")
            break
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
          print ("Done with Spamming, Press Ctrl-C again if you wish to quit, otherwise I'll keep searching")
          break

  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ("Phew! Done Searching")
    sys.exit()

if service_matches:
  first_match = service_matches[0]
  port = first_match["port"]
  name = first_match["name"]
  host = first_match["host"]

  sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
  sock.connect((host, port))

  print ("Happy Spamming")

  while True:
    try:
      string = 'test' + random.choice('abcdefghij') + '\n'
      sock.send(string)
      time.sleep(0.5)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print ("Done with Spamming")
      sys.exit()


sock.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).